# Concise way to reduce where one of the states throws an exception

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce, fold, vavr

I have a bunch of these:

```
Validation<String, Foo> a;
Validation<String, Foo> b;
Validation<String, Foo> c;
```

Here are some of their methods:

```
boolean isValid();
boolean isInvalid(); // === !isValid()
String getError();
```

Now, I was trying to do this:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c).reduce(
    Validation.valid(foo),
    (a, b) -> a.isValid() && b.isValid()
              ? Validation.valid(foo)
              : String.join("; ", a.getError(), b.getError())
);
```

There's the obvious issue that if only one of `a` or `b` is in error, then there's a needless `;`. But there's a more serious issue: `getError()` throws an exception if the validation is valid.

Is there a way I can write this lambda (or use something else in the [io.vavr.control.Validation library](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/master/vavr/src/main/java/io/vavr/control/Validation.java)) without making all 4 cases (`a && b`, `a && !b`, `!a && b`, `!a && !b`) explicit?

---

**EDIT**

To  be clearer, I wanted a result of `Validation<String, Foo>` in the end. I think it behaves like a "monad," in that way, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to describe what you are trying to achieve just using simple English. So you've got a bunch of `Validation<String, Foo>` objects and I understand you want to combine them into a single `Validation<String, Foo>` object. That means that if any of them is `invalid`, you want to end up in an `invalid` too, but have multiple error messages concatenated in case there are more than one. But it's not clear to me what do you want to do with the multiple `Foo` objects in case they are all `valid`. How do you want to combine them into a single one?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete - Yes, your understanding is spot on. The valid case is just a singleton representing that all (or the single) objects are valid, so they simply collapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is easier to solve in `Either` domain.

First, convert your stream of `Validation`s to a stream of `Either`s:

```
Stream<Either<String, Foo>> eithers = Stream.of(a, b, c)
    .map(Validation::toEither);
```

then combine them:

```
Either<String, Foo> result = Either.sequence(eithers)
    .mapLeft(seq -> seq.collect(Collectors.joining("; ")))
    .map(combinator); // fill in with combinator function that converts
                      // a Seq<Foo> into a single Foo
```

Since you didn't specify how you want to combine multiple valid `Foo` objects into a single one, I left it open for you to fill in the combinator function in the above example.

[`Either.sequence(...)`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Either.html#sequence-java.lang.Iterable-) will reduce many eithers into a single one by returning an `Either.Left` containing the sequence of left values if **any** of the provided eithers is a left, or an `Either.Right` containing a (possibly empty) sequence of all right values, if **none** of the provided eithers is a left.

#### Update:

There's a [`Validation.sequence(...)`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Validation.html#sequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method that can do it without converting into Either domain (which I somehow missed while creating my original answer -- thanks for pointing out):

```
Validation<Seq<String>, Seq<Foo>> validations = Validation.sequence(
        Stream.of(a, b, c)
            .map(v -> v.mapError(List::of))
);

Validation<String, Foo> result = validations
    .mapError(errors -> errors.collect(Collectors.joining("; ")))
    .map(combinator); // fill in with combinator function that converts
                      // a Seq<Foo> into a single Foo
```

You said that the `Foo` instances are the same, that means that you could use `Seq::head` in place of the combinator function. But you'll need to take care not to use an empty sequence of validations as input as it will cause `Seq::head` to throw `NoSuchElementException` in that case.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think [`Validation`'s `sequence` method](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/master/vavr/src/main/java/io/vavr/control/Validation.java) might be of use? I could not understand why it was an `Iterable`, but maybe it was provided for this purpose...

Comment: Actually yes, I somehow missed that method. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, I'm coming from C++ and having trouble with some basic things. `List::of` doesn't seems to exist. `Array::of` results in an error, `no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream<R> conforms to Iterable<? extends Validation<List<E>, T>>`. What is the appropriate function needed for, as I understand, simply creating a list?

Comment: Ah, I see. `List::of` was introduced in Java 9. However I need to stick to Java 8...

Comment: `List` in this case is `io.vavr.collection.List`. Sorry for the confusion, it's just that import statements usually decrease the signal-to-noise ratio so I tend do skip including them in my code snippets on stack overflow. But in this case it would've been better to include it. Actually, you could use any implementation of `io.vavr.collection.Seq` in place of that.

Comment: I think your solution would have worked, conceptually! Accepted. I self-answered with the solution I ended up going with, and why. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the output of your `reduce` is a **string** with the list of errors separated by `;`.

You are mixing the accumulator parameters:

- `a` is a partial result of the current reduction
- `b` is the object itself that you are iterating

I'd do something like this:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c).reduce(
    "", //initial state,
    (prevState, validationObject) -> {
        if (validationObject.isInvalid())
            return prevState + ";" + validationObject.getError();
        else
            return prevState;
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree with your approach if in the end I could accept a `""` as valid, but I would like to end up with a `Validation<String, Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Collectors.groupingBy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-). I think still you can improve false part set of string and join them, Output of below code is:

```
{false=[SomeException, ReallyBadProblem], true=[3, 5]}
```

Code example:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Validation<String,Integer> a = new Validation<>(true, null, 3);
        Validation<String,Integer> b = new Validation<>(true, null, 5);
        Validation<String,Integer> c = new Validation<>(false, "SomeException", null);
        Validation<String,Integer> d = new Validation<>(false, "ReallyBadProblem", null);

        //Stream.of(a,b,c).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v->v.isValid(), v->v.));

        TreeMap<Boolean, Set<Object>> map = Stream.of(a,b,c,d).collect((groupingBy(v->v.isValid(), TreeMap::new,
                                             mapping(v-> { return v.isValid() ? v.valid() : v.getError();}, toSet()))));

        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static class Validation<E, T>{

        boolean valid;
        T validVal;
        String error;


        public Validation(boolean valid, String error, T validVal) {
            super();
            this.valid = valid;
            this.error = error;
            this.validVal = validVal;
        }
        /**
         * @return the valid
         */
        public boolean isValid() {
            return valid;
        }
        /**
         * @param valid the valid to set
         */
        public void setValid(boolean valid) {
            this.valid = valid;
        }
        /**
         * @return the error
         */
        public String getError() {
            return error;
        }
        /**
         * @param error the error to set
         */
        public void setError(String error) {
            this.error = error;
        }

        public T valid() {
            return validVal;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I ended up going, though I think @Nandor (accepted answer) had it right. (His solution was based on a more current version of `io.vavr.control.Validation` than what's available to me (still `javaslang.control.Validation`). I figured out that `mapLeft` was renamed to `mapErrors`, but there were some missing bits related to `Seq` manipulation. Due to lack of familiarity with Java, I was unable to resolve my errors going this route.)

```
Validation<String, AdRequest> validation =
    Stream.of(
        validateTargetingRequest(adRequest),
        validateFlightRequest(adRequest, ad),
        validateCreativeRequest(adRequest)
    ).reduce(
        Validation.valid(adRequest),
        (a, b) -> {
          if (a.isValid() && b.isValid()) {
            return Validation.valid(adRequest);
          }
          if (a.isInvalid() && b.isInvalid()) {
            return Validation.invalid(String.join("; ", a.getError(), b.getError()));
          }
          // This seemingly overcomplicated structure was necessitated by the fact that getError
          // throws an exception when called on an Valid form of Validation.
          return a.isInvalid() ? a : b;
        }
    );
```